# Ayuda con un error en php explico lo que pasa abajo

Tags: php

en este codigo mando con js el id del producto por un boton y la cantidad

```
  echo '<p class="price">$'.$precio.'</p>';
   echo '<p class="buttons">';
   echo '<a href="detail.html" class="btn btn-default">Ver 
    Detalle</a>';
      //cantidad                                             
  echo '<input type="number" name="ja" value="0" id="jaa" class="la 
   ma">';
       //bootn que manda el id del producto                                   
  echo '<button value="'.$id.'" class="boton_compra">Añadir 
  Carrito</button>';
```

en el js tengo

```
 $(document).ready(inicio)

  function inicio(){

  $(".boton_compra").click(anade);
$("#carrito").load("functions/poncarrito.php");
$("#carrito2").load("functions/checkout.php");


}


 function anade(){

var fila = $(this).parents("p");

if(fila.find(".ma").val() >0){

$("#carrito").load("functions/poncarrito.php?p="+$(this).val());
$("#carrito").load("functions/poncarrito.php?
 c="+fila.find(".ma").val());

$("#carrito2").load("functions/checkout.php?p="+$(this).val());
$("#carrito2").load("functions/checkout.phpc="+fila.find(".ma").val());

}else{
alert("Ingrese cantidad");
}


}
```

lo cual mando al php que realice la operación

```
<?php
session_start();

if(isset($_GET['p'])){
  $_SESSION['producto'][$_SESSION['contador']] = $_GET['p']; 
  $_SESSION['contador']++;


 }

if (isset($_GET['c'])){
$_SESSION['cantidad'][$_SESSION['contador']] = $_GET['c'];
 }

include '../conexion/server.php';

 $suma = 0;
 for ($i=0; $i < $_SESSION['contador']; ++$i){
//echo "producto:".$_SESSION['producto'][$i]."-".$_GET['c'][$i]."<br>";

    $query = mysqli_query($conect,'SELECT * FROM Productos WHERE 
    id='.$_SESSION['producto'][$i].'');

    while ($fila = mysqli_fetch_array($query)) {


        $cab = $_SESSION['cantidad'][$i+1];
        $total = $fila['Precio']*$cab;

            echo '<tr>';
            echo '<td>'.$fila['Nombre'].'</td>';
            echo '<center><td>';

            echo '<center><input type=number name=ja class="la" 
      //aqui es el error
    value='.$cab.'></center>';
            echo '</td></center>';

            echo '<td>'.number_format($total,2).'</td>';
            echo '<td>';
            //echo $i;

            //echo '<input type=hidden name=ya class=na value='.$i.'>';
            //echo '<form action="functions/poncarrito.php" 
       method="post">';
            //echo '<button type=submit name="ka" 
   class="boton_borrar">borrar</button>';
            //echo '</form>';
            echo '<a href=functions/poncarrito.php?a='.$i.'>X</a>';

            echo '</td>';
            echo '</tr>';


                $suma += $total;


    }

}

if(isset($_GET['a'])){

    echo '<script>window.location="../tienda.php";</script>';

    unset($_SESSION['producto'][$_GET['a']]);
    unset($_SESSION['cantidad'][$_GET['a']+1]);
    $_SESSION['producto'] = array_values($_SESSION['producto']);
    $_SESSION['cantidad'] = array_values($_SESSION['cantidad']);
    $_SESSION['contador']--;

 }

 echo '<tr><td></td><td>Subtotal</td>
 <td>$'.number_format($suma,2).'</td></tr>';
 mysqli_close($conect);
 ?>
```

la cosa es que cuando ingreso la cantidad a ratos no manda el valor de la cantidad y cuando solo pongo la variable $_SESSION['cantidad']=get['c']
e imprimo eso en la tabla me da error y como lo puse ahora(en el php de arriba ) si imprime ese valor pero cada2 no imprime el valor y adicional como puedo validar para que cuando de click en un boton con el mismo valor en vez de que se el bucle siga corriendo se sume la cantidad y no aumente un producto a la lista.

le puse $cab = $_SESSION['cantidad'][$i+1]; porque si le dejo solo con $i me da error del offset si le paso como una variable sin indice me da error
LES AGRADECERIA MUCHISIMO SI PUEDEN AYUDARME

Comment: No entiendo lo que preguntas, porque me cuesta ubicar el error.

Comment: mirale de nuevo ya le puse donde esta el error osea le paso una cantidad pero cuando vuelvo a dar click el primero sale con la cantidad el segundo en blanco el tercero y cuarto salen con cantidad y el quinto no